# Beneficiary of an estate and transfers of large sum from UK to US

Tags: international, international-transfer, beneficiaries

I am being named as a beneficiary and I would like to know what are the best options for transferring funds from the UK to the US. I do not have an active account at the moment are there any ways to receive the funds and put it into some kind of account with verification of such funds listing me as a beneficiary?

I was expecting this to happen. It is not a scam I am a legitimate beneficiary of an estate.

Comment: Before you heard about this money, were you expecting to receive it? I ask because unless you were expecting to receive this, you are being scammed.

Comment: Yes, I was expecting to receive the money.

Comment: Can't they just send you a check?

Comment: I made some edits. The prevalence of scam questions with "inheritance" as a premise can cause questions like this to get buried as scams. This case is legitimate per OP. I hope this edit was not too presumptuous.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few standard ways:

1. Open a US bank or credit union account - most US banks will accept wires from foreign banks. You may need to get a SWIFT code in order for the UK bank to send the money to the right bank.
2. Use third party service - Nerd Wallet has a [list of companies](https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/banking/best-ways-to-wire-money-internationally/) that provide this kind of money transfer service. Examples include: Western Union, Xoom, and Transferwise. I haven't personally used any of these companies, so YMMV.

One thing to keep in mind is that you'll usually be charged a wire and/or service fee for the tranfer.